# Read and use information from additional file

Tags: javascript, node.js, text-files

I need to provide text information in a file, read it in java-script and then work with the output. The output is not supposed to go to a web page, but is a plugin for another program (RPG Maker MV).

I'm trying to load a text-file (*.txt) and output it with `document.write()`  I'm currently checking the code in Firefox. I get why this is prevented from working, but ultimately I do not want to run it in a Browser anyway. However I need to try the code before implementing it.

My text file looks like this:

```
What is the Capital of France?
-Berlin
-Paris [X]
-Koppenhagen

Who came up with the Theory of Evolution?
-Charles Darwin [X]
-Thomas Eddison
-Nicolas Flamel
```

The java-script should do something like:

```
var mytext=fs.readFileSync('quiz.txt');
document.write(mytext);
```

I could also use other file types than *.txt of course. Important is, that the quiz-file can be adapted without messing with the original java-script file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use the same code to read in file in NodeJS and from code running in a browser as they use very different APIs.

NodeJS relies on the [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module while the browser environment relies on the [File APIs](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) specified by W3C.